# inserting values into database

Tags: sql

```
private void BtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TANYA-PC;Initial Catalog=biore1;Integrated Security=True")) //or variable to it
   {
      string sqlQuery = @"INSERT INTO cottonpurchase VALUES(@slipno, @purchasedate, @farmercode, @farmername, @villagename, @basicprice, @weight, @totalamountbasic, @premium, @totalamountpremium, @totalamountpaid, @yeildestimates)";

      //NOTE: RENAME "MyTable" to your database table!!!!

      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConn))
      {
         cmd.Parameters.Add("@slipno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtSlipNo.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtSlipNo.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@purchasedate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart; //date of selection!
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(TxtFarmerCode.Text);
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmername", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TxtFarmerName.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@villagename", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Value = TxtVillageName.Text;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@basicprice", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtBasicPrice.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtBasicPrice.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@weight", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtWeight.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtWeight.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@totalamountbasic", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtTotalAmountBasic.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtTotalAmountBasic.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@premium", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtPremium.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtPremium.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@totalamountpremium", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtTotalAmountPremium.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtTotalAmountPremium.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@totalamountpaid", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtTotalAmountPaid.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtTotalAmountPaid.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;
      cmd.Parameters.Add("@yeildestimates", SqlDbType.Int).Value = (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(TxtYeildEstimates.Text)) ? int.Parse(TxtYeildEstimates.Text) : (object)DBNull.Value;

      sqlConn.Open();
      try
      {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute this I get an error that says :

> Input string was not in a correct
>   format.
>
> cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmercode",
>   SqlDbType.Int).Value =
>   int.Parse(TxtFarmerCode.Text);

Answer (score 2):

The error says it quite clearly - obviously, the text you're trying to convert to an `INT` is not really an `INT` number...

Maybe you need to do something more like this:

```
int farmerCode = -1;

if(int.TryParse(TxtFarmerCode.Text.Trim(), out farmerCode)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = farmerCode;
}
else
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = DBNull.Value;  // or whatever makes sense
}
```

It's a basic principle of defensive programming - don't just **assume** the conversion will work - it might not! Test it, use `int.TryParse`, and if your input is **not** a number, you need to deal with that (passing a `NULL` or some other mechanism - up to you)

Answer (score 0):

`TxtFarmerCode.Text` is not a valid `int` value

Good:  `int.Parse("123")`

Bad:  `int.Parse("Not an int")`

Answer (score 0):

What value is present in

```
TxtFarmerCode.Text
```

According to the SQL parameter, it needs to be an integer.  Sounds like you need to do some input validation to ensure that it is an integer before passing it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Your error does not match your code:

**Code**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value 
  = Convert.ToInt32(TxtFarmerCode.Text);
```

**Error**

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@farmercode", SqlDbType.Int).Value 
   = int.Parse(TxtFarmerCode.Text);
```

Other than that it seems obvious that TxtFarmerCode.Text does not translate into a valid int.
Make sure you test your values for validity before inserting them into the database, this goes for all your vars that have a limited range.
Obviously not all ints are valid for farmercode, so let the user have a list of valid farmercodes and make him choose one from the list. That way it's impossible to pick an incorrect farmercode.

**Suspected error inserting primary key**
You are trying to insert a new record, if `slipno` is your primary key, you should not allow a value other than `null` here, if you try to insert an existing key into the table you'll get an error, that should never happen.
It's best to let the database assign the primary key because that's foolproof.

**Normalization of database**
Why do you have `farmercode` and `farmername` in your table? Isn't farmercode the id of a farmer?
If so storing farmername as well is duplication of information.
You should just store the farmerid in the table. The farmer id then points to the primary key of table `farmers` which stores the name and other relevant info about farmers.

Links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization
http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm